# Change the size of histogram labels

Tags: r, graphics

Base graphing, some dummy data to state my case:

```
dat <- rnorm(n = 1000, m = 0, sd = 1) 
hist(dat, breaks = 5, labels = TRUE, freq = TRUE, main = "Title")
```

I added labels of the bins. Now, I'd like to change their size. I know a lot can be done with `cex` parameters:

```
hist(dat, breaks=5, labels = TRUE, freq = TRUE, main = "Title", cex.main = 0.5)
```

However it doesn't seem to handle the bar labels.

Any solution for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
H <- hist(dat, breaks = 5, main = "Title")
text(x = H$mids, y = H$counts, labels = H$counts, cex = 0.5, pos = 3)
```